# Will focus be set to invisible form controls using HTML5 autofocus?

Tags: forms, html, autofocus

As the title states: Will focus still be set on form controls with `autofocus="autofocus"` even if they are hidden with `display: none;` or `visibility: hidden;`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your question is whether a hidden field can steal autofocus from a visible one, the answer is no.

Hidden fields with an `autofocus` property get focus when they are made visible.

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joshearl/kJUD7/4/) that shows what happens if you have a visible field and a hidden field, then show the hidden field.

And here's a [variation](http://jsfiddle.net/joshearl/kJUD7/5/) that demonstrates what happens if the visible field does not have an `autofocus` property.

Comment: Thank you for the fiddle, but it doesn't work on Chrome 43.0.2357.132 on my Yosemite Mac.

Comment: When I click the button, it gives that button the focus. I don't think that autofocus is expected to do anything more. If you want to get the focus you need to call `$("focus-test").focus()`, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3):

The [HTML5 draft standard](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/editing.html#focusable) only requires that an element be "focusable" where focusable means:

> An element is focusable if the user agent's default behavior allows it
>   to be focusable or if the element is specially focusable, but only if
>   the element is either being rendered or is a descendant of a canvas
>   element that represents embedded content.
>        User agents should make the following elements focusable, unless platform conventions dictate otherwise:
>
> - `a` elements that have an `href` attribute
> - `link` elements that have an `href` attribute
> - `button` elements that are not disabled
> - `input` elements whose type attribute are not in the Hidden state and that are not disabled
> - `select` elements that are not disabled
> - `textarea` elements that are not disabled
> - `command` elements that do not have a disabled attribute
> - Elements with a `draggable` attribute set, if that would enable the user agent to allow the user to begin a drag operations for those
>     elements without the use of a pointing device
> - Editing hosts
> - Browsing context containers

It does say "but only if the element is either being rendered..." and the standard defines "rendered" as:

> An element is being rendered if it is in a Document, either its parent
>   node is itself being rendered or it is the Document node, and it is
>   not explicitly excluded from the rendering using either:
>
> - the CSS 'display' property's 'none' value, or
> - the 'visibility' property's 'collapse' value unless it is being treated as equivalent to the 'hidden' value, or
> - some equivalent in other styling languages.
>      Just being off-screen does not mean the element is not being rendered. The presence of the hidden attribute normally means the
>     element is not being rendered, though this might be overridden by the
>     style sheets.
>      User agents that do not honor author-level CSS style sheets are nonetheless expected to act as if they applied the CSS rules given in
>     these sections in a manner consistent with this specification and the
>     relevant CSS and Unicode specifications.

In short, the answer appears to be that if all other requirements are met then `display:none` won't be focused but `display:hidden` will - Assuming all browsers actually follow the spec.

Comment: `display:hidden` ? no such value for the `display` prop